# How do get the same effect as python's raw_input() in Perl?

Tags: python, perl

Python's `raw_input()` preserves all bash features like arrow keys and reverse searching...

But when I use Perl's `<>` to read from `stdin`,none of the features are supported any more...

What's the easiest way to do it as `raw_input` in Perl?

Comment: @eryksun ,why Perl requires more work to get fancy effects?

Comment: @eryksun ,I have a project which uses `<>` whenever possible, do I have to change all the occurrences of `<>` to `Term::ReadLine`?

Comment: you can leave your program unchanged but pipe input to it using the rlwrap utility: `rlwrap | perl yourscript.pl`

Comment: @ysth ,`rlwrap` has side effect...And I don't want to introduce more dependency.

Answer (score 5):

According to [the Python docs](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html),

> If the readline module was loaded, then raw_input() will use it to provide elaborate line editing and history features.

As stated in comments to the original post, you need to use an appropriate module, such as [Term::ReadLine](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Term%3a%3aReadLine) or [Term::ReadLine::Gnu](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Term%3a%3aReadLine%3a%3aGnu), to access those features.  This is no different than Python - if you want readline's features, you have to load a readline module, whether implicitly or explicitly.

But, yes, you will need to use your chosen readline module's input function instead of `<>` for any input which you want to have processed through readline.  ([Term::ReadLine::Perl](http://search.cpan.org/~ilyaz/Term-ReadLine-Perl-1.0303/) includes a Term::ReadLine::Perl::Tied module which might override `<>` to run through readline without requiring additional code changes, but T::RL::P hasn't been updated since 2009 and seems to be undocumented, so I wouldn't recommend it unless you have plenty of time to figure out how to use it.)